# Ruby on Rails createmethod doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I got a model `day` and a model `task`. `day` has many `tasks`. I'm using a nested_form for this. The user enters a `time` and  two variables, which a caculated to an `index`. The first task, with the highest `index` has a `starttime`= 8am.
Now I want to order the `tasks` by the `index` and add every task's `time` to the previous task's `starttime`.

My attempt to solve this:

```
def create
  @day = current_user.days.build(day_params)
  @day.save

  @day.tasks.each do |task|
    task.index = task.ur**2 + task.imp

  end

  if current_user.worktype = 1
    @tasks = @day.tasks.order(index: :desc)
    x = 0
    @tasks.each do |task|
      if x = 0
        task.starttime = Time.new.beginning_of_day + 8*60*60
        x = task.id
      else
        task.starttime = @day.task.find(x).starttime + @day.task.find(x).time*60
        x = task.id
      end
    end
  elsif current_user.worktype = 2
   ...
  end
  @day.save

  respond_to do |format|
    if @day.save
      format.html { redirect_to @day, notice: 'Day was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @day }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @day.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

But somehow `starttime` remains nil, when I want to print it out in the `view`

```
- @tasks.each do |task|
  ...
  = task.starttime.strftime("%H:%M")
```

I checked it in `rails console` too.

consolelog for POST:

```
Started POST "/days" for ::1 at 2016-08-04 02:19:03 +0200
Processing by DaysController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V",  "authenticity_token"=>"YaLq2XBUMltzCpZxvKBp5NQGUgiw/Ockto1r0zy/dZHU3HVlp4lpcsH/b3Q9WYas97ENlwRiPzCUdOiBC06GbA==", "day"=>{"tasks_attributes"=>{"1470269934695"=> {"description"=>"1", "ur"=>"1", "imp"=>"1", "time"=>"1"
, "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1470269939280"=>{"description"=>"2", "ur"=>"3",  "imp"=>"3", "time"=>"2", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Day"}
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 (0.0ms)  begin transaction
SQL (3.5ms)  INSERT INTO "days" ("user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-08-04 00:19:03.986762"],  ["updated_at", "2016-08-04 00:19:03.986762"]]
SQL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("description", "ur", "imp", "time", "day_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["description", "1"], ["ur", 1], ["imp", 1], ["time", 1], ["day_id", 11], ["created_at", "2016-08-04 00:19:03.992775"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-04 00:19:03.992775"]]
SQL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("description", "ur", "imp", "time", "day_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["description", "2"], ["ur", 3], ["imp", 3], ["time", 2], ["day_id", 11], ["created_at", "2016-08-04 00:19:03.994776"], ["updated_at", "2016-08-04 00:19:03.994776"]]
 (4.0ms)  commit transaction
Task Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."day_id" = ?  [["day_id", 11]]
Task Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."day_id" = ?  ORDER BY "tasks"."index" DESC  [["day_id", 11]]
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "tasks" SET "index" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "tasks"."id" = ?  [["index", 2], ["updated_at", "2016-08-04 00:19:04.006796"], ["id", 24]]
SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "tasks" SET "index" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "tasks"."id" = ?  [["index", 12], ["updated_at", "2016-08-04 00:19:04.009792"], ["id", 25]]
(3.6ms)  commit transaction
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
(0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/days/11
Completed 302 Found in 39ms (ActiveRecord: 14.6ms)
```

## EDIT

Building on @evanbike's answer I added a `task.save` everytime `starttime` is set. But nothing changed, so I tried and removed the If statement and now `starttime` is saved, but every `task` has the same time.

```
@tasks = @day.tasks.order(index: :desc)
x = 0
@tasks.each do |task|
  if x = 0
    task.starttime = Time.new.beginning_of_day + 8*60*60
    task.save
    x = task.id
  else
    task.starttime = @day.task.find(x).starttime + @day.task.find(x).time*60
    task.save
    x = task.id
  end
end
@day.save
```

I hope someone can help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you testing `starttime` to see whether it's nil?

Comment: @MarsAtomic updated may post

Comment: In your console log, when this `create` runs, can you see that a day object is being saved, along with the nested tasks? Also, have you tried using `save!` in order to explicitly throw errors in case something goes wrong with the save?

Comment: @MarsAtomic I posted the console log. At the end it says `(0.0ms)  begin transaction` and immediatly `(0.0ms)  commit transaction`, so I would assume its not entering the if statement.

Comment: You're not updating your @day before trying to save it. You extract all the tasks into @tasks and mess with them (trying to set `starttime` but you never update the fields of @day. @tasks is a separate array and has nothing to do with @day.tasks.

Comment: @MarsAtomic So would `@tasks.save` work or `task.save` for every task? sry I'm really stuck at this

Comment: Looks like you still need `task.save` after `task.index = task.ur**2 + task.imp`

Comment: @evanbikes the `index` is saved properly for every task, but the times still dont work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this, you are setting the `index` on the instance of the `task` in the `@day` association cache:

```
@day.tasks.each do |task|
  task.index = task.ur**2 + task.imp
end
```

Then, when you do this:

```
@tasks = @day.tasks.order(index: :desc)
```

...it makes a db call (since you're calling `order` on it) and return new instances—that don't have `index` set. If you called `sort` or some array method, it would use the stored instances

I think the *simplest* would be to `save` the instances of tasks after you set each of the values. Calling `sort` on the association would *probably* work, but it seems brittle.

Comment: I just realized, it has to be `if x == 0`... Now everything works fine. Thanks.